# In Rails 3 and jQuery, need to receive JSON data in an ajax:success

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm sure this is a really simply question, and I apologize if it is...

I'm using Rails 3 and jQuery, and am trying to bind an ajax:success to a remote form submission. The data that is being returned by the function will be in JSON format - and for some reason, I CAN NOT ACCESS the data. I don't understand how to fix it. Here's where I create the form:

```
Search: <%= form_tag(configurations_url(:format => :json), :remote => true, :method => :get) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :query %><br />
    <%= submit_tag "Search"%>
<% end %>
```

And then, on the bottom, I have this jQuery written to attach a function to the tail:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function() {   
    jQuery("div#configuration_search_form form").bind('ajax:success', function(json) {
        select_tag = jQuery("div#configuration_select_form form select")
        select_tag.empty()
        none_found_div = jQuery("div#no_configurations_found")
        select_form_div = jQuery("div#configuration_select_form")
        none_found_div.slideUp();
        select_form_div.slideUp();

        if(json.length > 0) {
            jQuery.each(json, function(index, config) {
                option_tag = "<option value='" + config.configuration.id + "'>" + config.configuration.name + "</option>"
                jQuery(option_tag).appendTo(select_tag)
            })
            select_form_div.slideDown();
        } else {
            none_found_div.slideDown();
        }
    })
}
```

So, the data that is being returned is json data, and it's perfectly valid. In fact, if I just write an ajax function by hand on the bottom, it works fine (that is, instead of using ajax:success, I just wrote an jQuery.ajax to react to a submit), but I'd rather not have all the extra code, since the form with the remote tag is so tidy. Is tehre a way I can fix this?

EDIT:

To clarify - what happens is, there is no error, but even if results are returned, it takes the trunk to unhide the 'no results found' div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but maybe the problem is that you're expecting the wrong number of arguments for your ajax:success callback. Try:

```
jQuery("div#configuration_search_form form").bind("ajax:success", function(json, status, xhr) {
      // Your code here...
    });
```

Probably first put an alert on json.toSource() and status and see what you get.

Comment: Good suggestion - I had the three vars in before, and in my experimenting, forgot to put them back. Sadly, same results when I put them in. Thanks though! Any other ideas?

Comment: What's the status var contains on the response?

Comment: OK, after looking at my objects more closely, using the jQuery.dump plugin, it turns out I had the argument order mixed up: should be xhr, json, status. So, I was looking at the request object, not the return data. The original example I had learned from had things in the wrong order. Thanks so much for your help!